# Is there a filter delimiter in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to build a list of servers in a Google Spreadsheet. Each server has multiple services, and I would like to be able to select a single service and see all the servers providing that service.

The problem I'm facing is the multiple services part. There's too many to provide a column for each service. Is there any sort of delimiter I can specify in the filter?

[image]

Or is there maybe a better way I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a possibility to do that, but its a bit complicated.

### Formula

```
=IF(LEN(B2)>1,INDEX(SPLIT(B2,";"),0,VLOOKUP(FILTERED!$B$1,$D$2:$E$4,2,0)),B2)

=FILTER(DATA!A:B,DATA!C:C=B1)
```

### Explained

In the first sheet (`DATA`) all data is presented. One helper column is added to capture the logic. Based on the value entered in sheet `FILTERED` the `VLOOKUP` formula will find a number, that will be used for the index function (`$D$2:$E$4`). That will show only a specific column, given by the split function. In the `FILTERED` sheet the result of the `DATA` sheet will be in filtered by the entered value in `FILTERED`.

### Screenshot

*data*
[image]

*filtered*
[image]

### Example

I've prepared an example file for you: **[Is there a filter delimiter in Google Spreadsheets?](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdDR1aGxjQ1JxVjRxYnlfYkozWDAwYkE)**

Comment: Nice solution. Yes, complicated but very nice.

Answer (score 1):

There are no filter delimiters or other tools which will achieve what you are looking for... that I know of.

One approach to the problem would be to make it a list of services rather than a list of servers.

For example, your data might look like:

```
server1     dns;dhcp;dc
server2     dc
server3     dns;dhcp;dc
```

the new data would look like:

```
dns      server1
dhcp     server1 
dc       server1 
dc       server2
dns      server3 
dhcp     server3 
dc       server3
```

Of course, this may mess with your other plans for this list.